# “Documents and Settings” junction is empty / What does it point to?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, directory-junction

I dual-boot Windows XP and Windows 7 and unfortunately it looks like it will not be possible to [merge the user profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/280596/) of the two operating systems. Therefore whenever I clean out the cruft from my drives (e.g., unused application data folders), I have to do it for both copies.

Today I was cleaning out the `Documents and Settings` folders of XP and 7. Windows XP’s copy is fine and contains the user profile directories as expected, but Windows 7’s copy is empty. I can `cd` into it and navigate to it in Explorer but there is nothing in it.

I *thought* it is supposed to point to `Users`, and thus “contain” the user profile directories, but I cannot find any confirmation to that effect.

What does the `Documents and Settings` junction point to and why is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

Although `Documents and Settings` is a junction point, it's not one designed to be read through. It's for compatibility. It does point at Users, and if you have, say, `Users\Synetech`, `Documents and Settings\Synetech` will get to the same spot. They really don't want you to use it though, and so the make it a hassle to do so, by making it appear empty (really, they took the read permission off of it).

Answer (score 0):

To recursively find all other `junction`s, use:

```
(Get-ChildItem . -Force | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select $_.FullName
```

If you wan to remove them, add (to the end):
`| Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`